# JQuery Event binding of Ajax Loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get JQuery to work on dynamically loaded content through ajax with event binding, similar to this: [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

However, I am not that good with java/Jquery and I cant seem to get jquery to work on the ajax content.  I started with this code:

```
(function($){
function floatLabel(inputType){
        $(inputType).each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var text_value = $(this).val();

            // on focus add class "active" to label
            $this.focus(function(){
                $this.next().addClass("active");
            });

            // on blur check field and remove class if needed
            $this.blur(function(){
                if($this.val() === '' || $this.val() === 'blank'){
                    $this.next().removeClass();
                    }
            });

            // Check input values on postback and add class "active" if value exists
            if(text_value!==''){
                $this.next().addClass("active");
                }
            });
    // Automatically remove floatLabel class from select input on load
    //$( "select" ).next().removeClass();
}
// Add a class of "floatLabel" to the input field
floatLabel(".floatLabel");
});
```

And I tried to bind the events like this:

```
(function($){
    var $this = $('.floatLabel');
    var text_value = $('.floatLabel').val();
$('.container').on('focus', '.floatLabel', function floatLabel(inputType){
    $(inputType).each(function(){
        $this.next().addClass('active');
        if(text_value!==''){
            $this.next().addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
$('.container').on('blur', '.floatLabel', function floatLabel(inputType){
        $(inputType).each(function(){
            if($this.val() === '' || $this.val() === 'blank'){
                $this.next().removeClass();
        }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

And this is the main html page:

```
<div class="container">
   <div id="ha">
     <script type="text/javascript">
      $( document ).ready(function() {
      $('#ha').load('example.com/createform');
});
     </script>
   </div>
</div>
```

Content loaded:

```
<div >
 <input class="floatLabel" name="example">
 <label for="example">example</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be solved with `$(document).ajaxComplete (function (){` and just duplicating the original code.  Thanks for the help everyone!